# Phalcon PHP: Update a primary natural key

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, phalcon, natural-key

Is there a good way to be able to update a table which has a natural key in Phalcon?

Consider this table:

```
people
------
person
created_at
updated_at
```

We're going to assume that the person field is unique and is the primary key.  I try to do the following:

```
$person = new People();
$person->person = 'Ed';
$person->save();

$personUpdate = People::findFirst('person = "Ed"');
$personUpdate->person = 'Bob';
$person->save();
```

What Phalcon ends up trying to do is to INSERT a new record, rather than to update the existing record.  What I *need* it to do is to UPDATE ... WHERE person = 'Ed';

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following...

```
<?php 
$personUpdate = People::findFirst('person = "Ed"');
$personUpdate->person = 'Bob';
$person->update();
```

Comment: Aw, man.  I was so hopeful!  Even with ->update(), nothing actually happens. (No CREATE nor UPDATE.)  As soon as I don't try to update the nat. key, everything's golden.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correct except ... `People::find`

`find` will prepare to fetch all data.. this means its in array  [Documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#understanding-records-to-objects)

You need to use `findFirst` instead of `find`

```
$personUpdate = People::findFirst('person = "Ed"');
$personUpdate->person = 'Bob';
$person->save();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I wasn't thinking and was just typing from my head.  I actually do use the findFirst to get a single object.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem, I'm sorry :(
I'm grateful for the answer, though, because it reminded me to change my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are using $person->update() instea of $personUpdate->update();

```
    <?php 
$personUpdate = People::findFirst('person = "Ed"');
$personUpdate->person = 'Bob';
$person->update();
```